# JQuery Contextmenu - handling right click on another object

Tags: jquery

I'm implementing contextmenu on SVG canvas object:

```
onContextMenu:function (x, y) {
    $('#contextMenuBase').remove();
    $('#canvas').append('<div id="contextMenuBase"' +
        'style="position: absolute; height:1px; width:1px; left: ' + x + 'px; top: ' + y + 'px; "></div>');

    $.contextMenu({
        selector:'#contextMenuBase',
        events:{
            hide:function () {
                $('#contextMenuBase').remove();
                $.contextMenu('destroy');
            }
        },
        callback:$.proxy(function (key, options) {
            switch (key) {
                case "delete_figure":
                    this.setColor("ff0000");
                    break;
                case "delete_table":
                    this.setColor("00ff00");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }, this),
        x:0,
        y:0,
        items:{
            delete_figure:{name:"Delete Figure"},
            delete_table:{name:"Delete Table"}
        }
    });
}
```

SVG element can't be referred with selector, so I created 1-pixel div in the pointer position and use it and trigged object. When user clicks outside menu, it destroyed.

I have only one challenge. If two objects have context menus and I make right click on first, then right click on second, first context menu should disappear, second - appear. But in my case hide() method called, first menu destroyed, but canvas doesn't receive right click event and, as result, doesn't create second menu.

How to fix it?

Thanks,
Boris.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to SVG elements in the selector, but only using their id and not their class.